# Nearby Places using Multiple dropdown CheckBoxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have simple dropdown with that i can select only thing but i want to select multiple dropdown and pass the values to google how can I pass please suggest something.
[image: check this image for reference Multiselct Nearby Place]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(function(){
      $('#lstFruits').multiselect().on('click',function(){
            for(var i=0; i<$('#lstFruits').val().length;i++){
                search_types(map.getCenter(),$('#lstFruits').val()[i]);
            }
          });
     });



        var map;
        var infowindow;
        var markersArray = [];
        var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(20.268455824834792, 85.84099235520011);
        var marker;
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        // var waypoints = [];                  
        function initialize() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                center: pyrmont,
                zoom: 14
            });
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            //document.getElementById('directionsPanel').innerHTML='';
            search_types();
           }

        function createMarker(place,icon) {
            var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: place.geometry.location,
                icon: icon,
                visible:true  

            });

            markersArray.push(marker);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.setContent("<b>Name:</b>"+place.name+"<br><b>Address:</b>"+place.vicinity+"<br><b>Reference:</b>"+place.reference+"<br><b>Rating:</b>"+place.rating+"<br><b>Id:</b>"+place.id);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });

        }
        var source="";
        var dest='';

        function search_types(latLng){
            clearOverlays(); 

            if(!latLng){
                var latLng = pyrmont;
            }
            var type = $('.case:checked').val();
            var icon = "images/"+type+".png";


            var request = {
                location: latLng,
                radius: 2000,
                types: [type] //e.g. school, restaurant,bank,bar,city_hall,gym,night_club,park,zoo
            };

            var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
            service.search(request, function(results, status) {
                map.setZoom(14);
                if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        results[i].html_attributions='';
                        createMarker(results[i],icon);
                    }
                }
            });

         }


        // Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them
        function clearOverlays() {
            if (markersArray) {
                for (i in markersArray) {
                    markersArray[i].setVisible(false)
                }
                //markersArray.length = 0;
            }
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        function clearMarkers(){
            $('#show_btn').show();
            $('#hide_btn').hide();
            clearOverlays()
        }
        function showMarkers(){
            $('#show_btn').hide();
            $('#hide_btn').show();
            if (markersArray) {
                for (i in markersArray) {
                    markersArray[i].setVisible(true)
                }

            }
        }

        function showMap(){

            var imageUrl = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=mm&chs=24x32&chco=FFFFFF,008CFF,000000&ext=.png';
            var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(imageUrl,new google.maps.Size(24, 32));
            var input_addr=$('#address').val();
            geocoder.geocode({address: input_addr}, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    if (results[0]) {
                        map.setZoom(14);
                        map.setCenter(latlng);
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: latlng, 
                            map: map,
                            icon: markerImage,
                            draggable: true 

                        }); 
                        $('#btn').hide();
                        $('#latitude,#longitude').show();
                        $('#address').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                        $('#latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
                        $('#longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
                        infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        search_types(marker.getPosition());
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                            infowindow.open(map,marker);

                        });


                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {

                            geocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker.getPosition()}, function(results, status) {
                                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                    if (results[0]) {
                                        $('#btn').hide();
                                        $('#latitude,#longitude').show();
                                        $('#address').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                                        $('#latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
                                        $('#longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
                                    }

                                    infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                                    var centralLatLng = marker.getPosition();
                                    search_types(centralLatLng);
                                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                                }
                            });
                        });


                    } else {
                        alert("No results found");
                    }
                } else {
                    alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
                }
            });

        }   

    </script>
```

and this is my html:

```
<select id="lstFruits" multiple="multiple" class="case btn btn-default">

    <option name="mytype" class="case" id="school"  value="school">School</option>
    <option  name="mytype" class="case" id="restaurant"  value="restaurant"/><label for="restaurant">Restaurant</option>
    <option name="mytype" class="case"  id="hospital"  value="hospital"/><label for="hospital">Hospital</option>
    <option  name="mytype"  class="case" id="bus_station"  value="bus_station"/><label for="bus_station">Bus Stopedge</option>
    <option name="mytype"  class="case" id="park"  value="park"/><label for="park">Park</option>


    <option name="mytype"  class="case" id="bank"  value="bank">Bank</option>
    <option  name="mytype"  class="case" id="bar"  value="bar"/><label for="restaurant">Bar</option>
    <option name="mytype"  class="case" id="movie_theater"  value="movie_theater"/><label for="movie_theater">Movie Theatre</option>
    <option  name="mytype"  class="case" id="night_club"  value="night_club"/><label for="bus_station">Night Club</option>
    <option name="mytype"  class="case" id="zoo"  value="zoo"/><label for="park">Zoo</option>

    <option name="mytype"  class="case" id="gym"  value="gym">Gym</option>
    <option  name="mytype"  class="case" id="atm"  value="atm"/><label for="restaurant">ATM</option>
    <option name="mytype"  class="case" id="spa"  value="spa"/><label for="movie_theater">SPA</option>


</select>
```

Comment: plz make a fiddle...

Comment: this is my fiddle but map is not loading i am using first time fiddle..   https://jsfiddle.net/rahulsingh92/vwt1dgpu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **normal html Select Box** then
first replace `$('.case').click(function(){...}` callback with

```
$('#lstFruits').on('click',function(){
        for(var i=0; i<$('#lstFruits').val().length;i++){
            search_types(map.getCenter(),$('#lstFruits').val()[i]);
        }
});
```

If you are using **Bootstrap Multiselect** then comment out `$('#lstFruits').multiselect().on('click',function(){ ... }` and use this

```
$('#lstFruits').multiselect({
        onChange: function(element, checked) {
                var types = $('#lstFruits option:selected');
                $(types).each(function(index, value){
                    search_types(map.getCenter(),$(this).val());
                });
        }
});
```

Now pass `type` as the second argument and **comment out the line** `var type = $('.case:checked').val();`

```
function search_types(latLng,type){
   //your existing code
   //var type = $('.case:checked').val();
}
```

Comment: thanx man I have implemented Your suggestions, it's working fine for multiple select, when I am changing to checkboxses it's not working by the way alot of thanx man

Comment: check my code i have updated, I'm using bootstrap multiselect js and css cdn  only .multiselect() i have added  to get checkbox view         $(function(){
         $('#lstFruits').multiselect().on('click',function(){
    for(var i=0; i<$('#lstFruits').val().length;i++){
    search_types(map.getCenter(),$('#lstFruits').val()[i]);
    }
     });
   });